# How to structure JSON code in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a newbie question.

The Ruby code below returns JSON shown in Output1. How do I modify this to return the JSON shown in Output2 i.e., each record is within customer record.

### Code:

```
def index
    @customers = Customer.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render json: @customers.to_json}
    end
end
```

### Output1:

```
[
    {
        "address":"123 Main Ave, Palo Alto, CA",
        "created_at":"2012-07-10T19:49:24Z",
        "id":1,
        "name":"ACME Software Inc.",
        "phone":"1-650-555-1500",
        "updated_at":"2012-07-10T19:49:24Z"
    },
    {
        "address":"555 Art Drive, Mountain View, CA",
        "created_at":"2012-07-10T19:50:19Z",
        "id":2,
        "name":"My Company",
        "phone":"1-415-555-1000",
        "updated_at":"2012-07-10T19:50:19Z"
    }
]
```

### Output2:

```
[
    {
        "customer":{
            "address":"123 Main Ave, Palo Alto, CA",
            "created_at":"2012-07-10T19:49:24Z",
            "id":1,
            "name":"ACME Software Inc.",
            "phone":"1-650-555-1500",
            "updated_at":"2012-07-10T19:49:24Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "customer":{
            "address":"555 Art Drive, Mountain View, CA",
            "created_at":"2012-07-10T19:50:19Z",
            "id":2,
            "name":"My Company",
            "phone":"1-415-555-1000",
            "updated_at":"2012-07-10T19:50:19Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in Rails 3.2, you can do :

```
format.json {render json: @customers.to_json(:root => true)}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want this behavior for all models, you can do

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

in an initializer.

For a single model, use

```
self.include_root_in_json = true
```

in the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea WHY you want this, but here's one easy way:

```
format.json {render json: @customers.map{ |x| {'customer' => x } }.to_json}
```

Comment: If your API can send back multiple types of data for one request (very useful in multiplexing calls to cut down chattiness on a mobile device modem) this format tags each data package with its data type. In other words, sending the object type along with the object's data lets your client be much more intelligent when parsing.